# Manage document versions in Readthedocs

Tags: documentation, read-the-docs

I am having hard time understanding Read the Docs version control for my documentation (may be because of lack my understanding!).

All my project documents are hosted on GitHub and I am trying to setup versions for my document that needs to be in-sync with the latest development releases.

1. How to manage these doc versions/what are the configurations in sphinx config?
2. Is there a way I can time travel my document. i.e., If I want to see
   any older version of my doc, how can I (re)publish this on Read the
   Docs?

**Currently, what I am doing:**

For a particular development release cycle (say `rc1.2`), I communicate with the engineers for the changes and I make those changes to my doc; merge the feature PR to main branch. On merging, Read the Doc builds a latest version (`latest` is pointing to `main`).
How to see the changes for `rc1.0`, `rc1.1`. I am thinking of creating something like `change_log.rst` and list the changes for each releases. But this would be something only for reference. How to manage these in Read the docs on admin/GitHub?

Comment: "If your project has any tags or branches with a name following semantic versioning, we also create a stable version, tracking your most recent release. If you want a custom stable version, create either a tag or branch in your project with that name." https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/versions.html

Comment: yes, I read that. But how to create a tag or branch for my docs project. There is already a tag in dev repo.

Comment: Once you have tags/branches created on your Git project, you have to "Activate those versions" on Read the Docs to be built. Go to your Read the Docs' project page and click on "Versions". From there, select the version you want to activate and then save it. After that, it will be built and hosted on Read the Docs.